# What does leadership do?

Tags: empire-defense-2

Damage and range are obvious, but I can not figure out how important leadership is. How much does it matter, how does it influence my soldiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leadership increases the attack damage of soldiers. In fact it is more important than upgrading soldiers or unlocking some heroes. Troops with a high rate of fire will be scary when the leadership is high (the base attack doesn't make much difference with an upgraded weapon).

Answer (score 0):

Leadership doesn't affect your soldiers but it can strength General's combat power.